# Updating PATH environment variable permanently in Docker container

Tags: environment-variables, docker, linux-containers

I tried adding to the `PATH` in the files `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile` as follow.

```
PATH = $PATH:/required/path
```

However, it does not work. Then I tried with adding the line show, which did not work either.

```
export PATH
```

It did not work even after restarting the container and the host both.

Comment: The question was after creating the container and made some modifications. Not while creating the container using Docker configuration file.

Answer (score 200):

If you want to include a `/new/path` in the **Dockerfile**, adding the line:

`ENV PATH "$PATH:/new/path"`

in **Dockerfile** should work.

Comment: Note that the quotes are important.

Comment: This works but not for all users. Any idea how to make it available for everyone?

Comment: It's not possible with ENV, instead you'll have to use something similar to /etc/environment:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15383

Comment: This worked fine for me. I needed to add a JDK to an image (I couldn't just use apt install, had to be downloaded and extracted separately), so I added ENV JAVA_HOME "/path/to/jdk" and ENV PATH "${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}". Once I rebuilt the image, the JDK was available to the build user.

Comment: is there a special way to do this in LSF from IBM?

Comment: This does not work if USER is specified. echo $PATH shows the correct path, but the shell does not honor the path change

Answer (score 42):

#### 1. The correct answer

The best voted answer suggests to add `ENV PATH "$PATH:/new/path"` to the **Dockerfile**, and this should indeed work.

#### 2. So why doesn't it work for me?

As noted in some comments/answers, the solution 1. does not work for some people.

The reason is that the `PATH` can be overwritten by some script like `.bashrc` when running the docker container, giving thus the impression that the `ENV PATH...` did not work, but it theoretically did.

To solve the issue, you need to append to the `.bashrc` the correct `PATH` by adding the below command to your Dockerfile:

`RUN echo "export PATH=/new/path:${PATH}" >> /root/.bashrc`

Comment: Ok, but how to reload the environment so that bash saw the changes?

Comment: @Alexander You'd use `. /root/.bashrc` to source the updated file in your existing bash session. By default when opening a new session that change should be caught otherwise.

Comment: I would do `echo "export ... \${PATH} ..."` (escaping the dollar sign), in order to make it expandable by bash, not by Docker

Answer (score 13):

Put in your Dockerfile a line `ENV PATH xxx` see an example in this Dockerfile https://gist.github.com/deepak/5933685

Answer (score 12):

I got the answer for this question in irc chat. Given here for the benefit of anyone who may come across this. Many people have given wrong answers as update the `~/.profile` but that did not work. So use the answer below.

Update the file `~/.bashrc` for user or update the file `/etc/enviroment` global for global change which will apply for all users.

In `.bashrc` export PATH: `export PATH=$PATH:/new/path/bin`

In enviroment: `PATH=$PATH:/new/path/bin`

Comment: I think Jason Gao's answer should be the accepted one considering the question relates to Docker. Updating bash profiles is a fine way to store variables on a standard non-containerized environment but its cleaner to include an ENV step in your Dockerfile if you are deploying in a container.

Comment: The method for 'in environment' is incorrect according to this Ubuntu Document (Note: Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment.). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment

Comment: So setting the .bashrc file seems to only work when running as an interactive terminal, which makes sense as it would run the users default shell.  Using that file will not work for running commands inside of the container unless you send them though bash.

Comment: Someone please modify this. I've just wasted 1 hour banging my head against why it wouldn't expand. ty @dangeroushobo

Answer (score 7):

The difference between interactive and non-interactive shells is not noted. Hence, that's why above solutions sometimes seem to work and sometimes not.

`bashrc` files typically get skipped for non-interactive shells. For instance in Debian, the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file very clearly states:

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

- A `RUN` command in Dockerfile invokes a *non-interactive* shell. And the path set by `ENV` will be taken and `bashrc` scripts will not run.
- `docker run -it <image> /bin/bash` invokes an *interactive* shell. `bashrc` will be run and *could* override anything set in `ENV`, if the for instance `PATH` is not defined in the usual `PATH=$PATH:/...` syntax in any of the `bashrc` scripts.

In order to be safe and consistent between the 2 modes of operation, one could do in Dockerfile:

```
ENV PATH /master/go/bin:${PATH}
RUN echo "${PATH}" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Note that `/etc/bash.bashrc` is the Debian location and probably is different on other distribution images.

Answer (score 2):

This is my docker file, on Centos I have extracted and set java home path and it worked for me.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM  centos:7
RUN yum update -y yum install -y tar
COPY jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt/
WORKDIR /opt
RUN tar -xvf jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN chmod -R 755 jdk1.7.0_80
RUN echo export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_80 >> /etc/profile
RUN echo export PATH='$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' >> /etc/profile
ENV JAVA_HOME "/opt/jdk1.7.0_80"
ENV PATH "${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
```