# docker-compose adding to PATH

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to add some paths to my PATH in docker-compose.yml

in docker-compose.yml I have tried

```
app:
    ...
    environment:
        - PATH /code/project
```

however that just overwrites the existing PATH - whereas I want to add to the existing PATH

Answer (score -8, accepted):

to add a single location to PATH in your docker-compose.yml file:

```
app
    environment:
        - PATH=/code/project:$PATH
```

to add multiple locations to your PATH in your docker-compose.yml file

```
app
    environment:
        - PATH=/code/project:/code/lib:/foo/bar:$PATH
```

to add to your PYTHONPATH

```
app
    environment:
        - PYTHONPATH=/code/project:/code/lib:/foo/bar
```

Comment: here $PATH would be replaced with the value defined on the machine on which you run the docker-compose command. This would not extend the value of the original PATH environment variable as it was in the docker image.

Comment: @Thomasleveil - Interesting -  I have tested extending PATH using the code above and it works - have tested several times

Comment: are you sure the `PATH` value wasn't the same on both your docker host system and your docker image, as a coincidence?

Comment: @Thomasleveil - just checked, the path for the docker container is not on the host system. In fact that path `code` is created just for the docker image

Comment: I'm sorry I maintain it does not work, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thomasleveil/7428032dcfe9a13432e0), using docker-compose v1.5.2 on CentOS 6.7

Comment: it works on `PYTHONPATH` Please be careful on your workdir.

Comment: @Thomasleveil is correct. This is simply using the value from the host where you're running `docker-compose` from. The fact that the same `PATH` exists in the container, does not mean "it works" in the way that the OP describes. Try adding values to `PATH` in your host shell, and then run `docker-compose`. You'll see that they show up in the container `PATH`. Then try clearing `PATH` in your host shell, and you'll see that it no longer "works". Additionally, using `env_file` to do this will simply interpret `$PATH` as a string literal.

Comment: My experience with Docker for Windows running a Windows Image is that @Thomasleveil is right.

Answer (score 23):

A `docker-compose.yml` does not offer you any mean to extend an environment variable which would already be set in a Docker image.

The only way I see to do such things is to have a Docker image which expects some environment variable (let's say `ADDITONAL_PATH`) and extends **at run time** its own `PATH` environment variable with it.

---

Let's take the following *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM busybox
ENV PATH /foo:/bar
CMD export PATH=$PATH:$ADDITIONAL_PATH; /bin/echo -e "ADDITIONAL_PATH is $ADDITIONAL_PATH\nPATH is $PATH"
```

and the following *docker-compose.yml* file (in the same directory as the *Dockerfile*):

```
app:
  build: .
```

Build the image: `docker-compose build`

And start a container: `docker-compose up`, you will get the following output:

> app_1 | ADDITIONAL_PATH is
>
> app_1 | PATH is /foo:/bar:

Now change the *docker-compose.yml* file to:

```
app:
  build: .
  environment:
    - ADDITIONAL_PATH=/code/project
```

And start a container: `docker-compose up`, you will now get the following output:

> app_1 | ADDITIONAL_PATH is /code/project
>
> app_1 | PATH is /foo:/bar:/code/project

---

Also note a syntax error in your *docker-compose.yml* file: there must be an equal sign (`=`) character between the name of the environment variable and its value.

```
environment:
    - PATH=/code/project
```

instead of

```
environment:
    - PATH /code/project
```

Comment: This will also work in the `Dockerfile`: `ENV="/my/new/path"${PATH}". Note that the quotes are important. I recommend adding this to your answer. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722548/updating-path-environment-variable-permanently-in-docker-container).

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old thread, but I think there are a couple of things that can be clarified.

Through `docker-compose` file one can only address variables from the host machine, therefore it is **NOT possible** to extend image's PATH from docker-compose.yml:

```
app:
    ...
    environment:
        - PATH=/code/project:$PATH
```

On the other hand, using RUN or CMD EXPORT directive will not suffice due to **EXPORTED** variables not persisting through images. Since every Dockerfile directive generates an intermediate image, these values will be reflected in them and not in the main image where you actually need them.

The best option would be to use build option in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  app:
    build: .
```

and adding ENV option to a **Dockerfile**:

> `ENV PATH /path/to/bin/folder:$PATH`

This is suggested in issue [#684](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/684) and I would also suggest looking at an answer: [docker ENV vs RUN export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379393/docker-env-vs-run-export).

Answer (score 2):

You can **add** your value. 
To do so you need to know name or ID of the container, run it to know:

```
docker ps
```

This will print details of all running containers. Look for your container and copy its ID or name. Then run this:

```
docker inspect <container ID>
```

It will print all values of specified container. Look for **ENV** section and find **PATH** environment variable. Then copy its value, add your changes and extend it with your new values then set it again in your docker-compose.yml "environment" section.

```
app
environment:
    - PATH=value-you-copied:new-value:new-value:etc
```

Note that you shouldn't remove anything from initial value of PATH, just extend it and add new value.

Answer (score 0):

@Thomasleveil's answer works only for containers built directly from the docker-compose file (via the `build`). And you have no control over the command executed.

I needed this functionality for containers downloaded from (our) repository where this does not quite work.

I have found solution using the `entrypoint` and `command`.

Lets have some base container `base` and another one, `java7`, that is based upon it. And finaly some docker-compose using the `java7` container to run some stuff.

Probably the most important file here, `entrypoint.sh`

```
$ cat base/script/entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="$PATH_ADD:$PATH"
echo "Path modified to $PATH"
exec $@
```

Dockerfile for `base` container

```
$ cat base/Dockerfile
FROM xxx
# copy entrypoint script that extends current PATH variable by PATH_ADD
COPY script/entrypoint.sh /usr/sbin

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Dockerfile for `java7` container

```
$ cat java7/Dockerfile
FROM base
# download java7
curl ... /opt/java/jdk7
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/java/jdk7
```

Commands run by docker-compose

```
$ cat sbin/run-app1.sh
exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version

$ cat sbin/run-app2.sh
exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

Docker-compose using these:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    image: java7
    command: run-app1.sh
    environment:
      PATH_ADD: /app/sbin
    volumes:
      - "./sbin:/app/sbin:cached"
  app2:
    image: java7
    command: run-app2.sh
    environment:
      PATH_ADD: /app/sbin
    volumes:
      - "./sbin:/app/sbin:cached"
```

File structure

```
$ tree
.
├── base
│   ├── script
│   │   └── entrypoint.sh
│   └── Dockerfile
├── java7
│   └── Dockerfile
├── sbin
│   ├── run-app1.sh
│   └── run-app2.sh
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: run-app1.sh is wrongly listed twice from the tree command. the second one should be run-app2.sh