# How to append to path in dockerfile or docker run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So I have written a dockerfile and when I run the image the PATH is

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I want to add another entry to the PATH so in my dockerfile I tried

```
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/some/new/path"
```

However when I tried that the PATH changed to include my personal path (with `/some/new/path` appended). How do I arrange it so that `/some/new/path` is appended without changing the rest of the PATH to my personal PATH?

The docker image is being run with `--entrypoint /bin/bash` and argument `--norc` which I'd prefer not to change if possible.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Can you add the complete Dockerfile to the question?  Can you just install your software into one of the directories that's already on `$PATH` (it's isolated inside your image)?

Comment: I can't post the dockerfile as it's proprietory. It's mostly package installation with apt-get and some downloading and unzipping. I don't think there's anything unusual. It's not possible to install this particular piece of software somewhere other than where it wants to go, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 13):

To append the containers $PATH try something along these lines in the Dockerfile:

```
ENV PATH /usr/local/postgres-$PG_MAJOR/bin:$PATH
```

Resources:

- [Updating PATH environment variable permanently in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722548/updating-path-environment-variable-permanently-in-docker-container/38905161)
- [In a Dockerfile, How to update PATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093612/in-a-dockerfile-how-to-update-path-environment-variable)
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Comment: As I said in my question, I tried that but it wasn't what I wanted as my own path gets put into the image.

Comment: Oh, that's no good. The way I read the docs it would append the value you specify to $PATH. Sorry about that.